# How to set the data label for stacked bar graph to include total count for each bar in Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-visualization, amazon-quicksight

In Quick sight, when using the stacked bar graph, the data label will just show the count for each group, no total number shown. It is not convenient since audiences need to add those number by themselves. Would anybody help me solve this problem? cheers

Comment: can't viewers look at the x or y axis to get a gauge for the total?

Comment: @JDD thanks for your reply, but I don't think that gonna work? does the axis could should the total of each bar anywhere?